# uninitialized constant Twitter::Search (NameError) ~ Ruby noob

Tags: ruby, twitter, terminal

I'm trying to run the code below for a Twitter bot I am building (not to spam people if that helps my cause) but I keep getting this error message:

```
uninitialized constant Twitter::Search (NameError)
```

I'm a total noob when it comes to programming, especially ruby. Please can someone help!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.oauth_token = "XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.oauth_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end

Twitter.user

  client = Twitter::Client.new
  search = Twitter::Search.new

  search.containing("news").containing("journalism").containing("newsrooms").result_type("recent").per_page(3).each do |x|
    until x.text.length <= 90 do
      y = x.text.chop!
    end
    y = "via: " + y
    client.update("#{y}")
    end
```

Comment: I would HIGHLY encourage you to remove the keys/tokens and replace them with filler strings. That's a security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: I don't know about twitter gem, but as long as you are using the current Ruby system, you shouldn't need to write `require 'rubygems'`.

Comment: Thanks Abraham. Like I said. I'm a total n00b. @Sawa: so I shouldn't have require 'rubygems'? Do you think that will help?

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` is needed for Ruby 1.8 but not for Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am under the assumption that you are using the latest version of the twitter gem.

According to the documentation ([Twitter Documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter)), *there is no* `Twitter::Search`
Doing searches seems to be done via the `Twitter::API.search` method ([Method Documentation here](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API#search-instance_method))